# Select unique records without natural keys

Tags: ruby, datamapper, sqlite3-ruby, ruby-datamapper

For example, I have table `names`: `id integer primary key, name text unique` and unique index for `names(name)`.

I want to select records by index-style syntax: `(n12, nBill) = (Name[12], Name['Bill'])` or with `Name.get['Smitt']`.

As documentation [says](http://datamapper.org/docs/find.html), it can be done with "natural keys", but how create them at SQLite?

update:
 @Frost: As [Spotlight on... Composite Keys](http://datamapper.org/articles/spotlight_on_cpk.html) says, records with composite keys must be called with both keys:
`Name.get(1, 'Smitt')`, it is wrong for me. I need something to select record by **any** key:

`Name[1] == Name['Smitt']`.

Answer (score 0):

As the [property docs](http://datamapper.org/docs/properties.html) say, you can create natural keys by passing `:key => true` to your `:name` property, like so:

```
class Name
  property :name, :unique => true, :key => true
end
```

That should enable you to do `Name["Bill"]` or `Name.get("Bill")`.

If you add `:key` to more than one property, you can have composite keys as well.

Comment: I confused:

when I have `id, Serial` and `:name, :key=>true`, auto_migrade generate only single primary key for `id` and 2 unique indexes, for `name` and for `id`.  

When I change `Serial` to `Integer, :unique=>true, :key=>true`, auto_migrate will generate `PRIMARY KEY("id", "name")`.  

Why so?